# AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'encode' - using ezgmail (python)

Tags: python, email

I'm using ezgmail to send out automated emails but email_policybase.py is throwing an AttributeError. Any insight would be much appreciated!

`ezgmail.send('sender@gmail.com', 'test', 'test')`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Automation\mailer.py", line 3, in <module>
    ezgmail.send('sender@gmail.com', 'test', 'test')
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ezgmail\__init__.py", line 603, in send
    msg = _createMessage(sender, recipient, subject, body, cc, bcc, mimeSubtype, _threadId=_threadId) 
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ezgmail\__init__.py", line 499, in _createMessage
    rawMessage = {"raw": base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_bytes()).decode("ascii")}
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\email\message.py", line 208, in as_bytes
    g.flatten(self, unixfrom=unixfrom)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\email\generator.py", line 116, in flatten
    self._write(msg)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\email\generator.py", line 199, in _write
    self._write_headers(msg)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\email\generator.py", line 422, in _write_headers
    self._fp.write(self.policy.fold_binary(h, v))
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\email\_policybase.py", line 337, in fold_binary
    folded = self._fold(name, value, sanitize=self.cte_type=='7bit')
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\email\_policybase.py", line 369, in _fold
    parts.append(h.encode(linesep=self.linesep, maxlinelen=maxlinelen))
                 ^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

I added some print statements into _policybase.py to print the value of h and the type and got the following:

```
1.0 || <class 'email.header.Header'>
7bit || <class 'email.header.Header'>
sender@gmail.com || <class 'email.header.Header'>
False || <class 'bool'>
```

I tried casting h to a header.Header object which lead to a new AttributeError:

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Automation\mailer.py", line 3, in <module>
    ezgmail.send('sender@gmail.com', 'test', 'test')
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ezgmail\__init__.py", line 603, in send
    msg = _createMessage(sender, recipient, subject, body, cc, bcc, mimeSubtype, _threadId=_threadId) 
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ezgmail\__init__.py", line 499, in _createMessage
    rawMessage = {"raw": base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_bytes()).decode("ascii")}
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\email\message.py", line 208, in as_bytes
    g.flatten(self, unixfrom=unixfrom)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\email\generator.py", line 116, in flatten
    self._write(msg)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\email\generator.py", line 199, in _write
    self._write_headers(msg)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\email\generator.py", line 422, in _write_headers
    self._fp.write(self.policy.fold_binary(h, v))
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\email\_policybase.py", line 337, in fold_binary
    folded = self._fold(name, value, sanitize=self.cte_type=='7bit')
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\email\_policybase.py", line 371, in _fold
    header.Header(h)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\email\header.py", line 217, in __init__
    self.append(s, charset, errors)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\email\header.py", line 295, in append
    s = s.decode(input_charset, errors)
        ^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'decode'```
````

Comment: The issue seems to be `for h, v in msg.raw_items():` in `generator.py`. Why is `h` a boolean in the first place, it should be a string.

Comment: Everything expects raw_items to be a `list[tuple[str, str]]`

Comment: Anyway, this is either a bug in `ezgmail` or `email`, it doesn't seem like a bug in your code.

Comment: I agree, the issue seems to be in the email module. I can't figure out where the boolean is even coming from. I'll try modifying 'for h, v in msg.raw_items(): in generator.py' to see what's happening and if I can't cast it back to a string. Thanks for the input!

Comment: generator.py is looking for a sender argument so sender='[sender]' needs to be added into the ezgmail.send() call after the message body argument.

Answer (score 1):

email\generator.py can take a sender argument. Including `sender = myaddress@mydomain` into ezgmail.send() fixes the issue. It appears there is a bug where, when a sender argument is not passed, it defaults to a boolean value of False.

Comment: The documentation of `ezgmail()` says this is an optional argument  and it's ignored by Gmail. It seems like this is a bug if leaving it out causes an error.

Comment: And none of the examples use this option.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).